# MFC Toggle Radio Button Is Delayed

Tags: mfc, radio-button, cdialog, cbutton

I have a radio button that is a CButton in a CDialog.
When the user clicks the radio button, the function `OnClickedRadioButton` is called.

Inside `OnClickedRadioButton` I toggle the button by calling this function:

```
void toggleButton(CButton& theButton)
{
    switch(theButton.GetCheck())
    {
        case BST_UNCHECKED:
        {
            theButton.SetCheck(BST_CHECKED);
            break;
        }
        case BST_CHECKED:
        {
            theButton.SetCheck(BST_UNCHECKED);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            theButton.SetCheck(BST_UNCHECKED);
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile & run the program:
(i) if the radio button is checked on, I can click it to clear it.
(ii) if the radio button is unchecked, I click it and nothing happens.  But if I click on a different program (i.e. visual studio) and then click back on the CDialog, the radio button checks on.

I've looked & tried functions `Cwnd::UpdateDialogControls` and `Cwnd::UpdateData`, but I was not able to get these to solve my problem.

Comment: Are you aware that when you click on the radio button, and, use the SetCheck method, that you are in effect causing another OnClickedRadioButton event?

Comment: @rrirower No, I was not aware.  I'm new to MFC. Do you know a good way to allow the user to toggle the radio button?

Comment: You may be using the wrong control.  "Toggling" usually implies a check box because it can be 'on' or 'off'.

Comment: @rrirower Yeah, I saw that, but I want the visual of the radio button rather than the check box.

Comment: @rriower The radio button toggles now.  However, if the button is unchecked & I click on another program, when I click on the CDialog that has the radio button, the radio button gets checked automatically.  Any ideas what causes this?

Comment: Without seeing more, I'd say there's a bug in your code.  I'd also say you're making a mistake if you're using just **one** radio button.  That's not an appropriate use of that control in terms of User Interface in the context you've described.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem was related to @rrirower comment that SetCheck will cause another OnClickedRadioButton event.

Regardless of the root cause, the quick fix to allow my implementation to toggle a radio button between`BST_CHECKED` and `BST_UNCHECKED` was to set the radio button's Auto property to False.

To do this:
1) Open the resource in visual studio
2) Right-click on the radio button and select Properties
3) In the Appearance section, set the Auto property to False.

Here is the overall solution to toggle a single radio button in a subclass of CDialog (assuming you already added a Dialog resource with a radio button with ID IDC_RADIO):

1) Add radio button IDC_RADIO to the message map by placing this line

```
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_RADIO, OnBnClickedRadioButton)
```

between BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP and END_MESSAGE_MAP.

2) Add the handler function to your subclass of CDialog

```
void OnBnClickedRadioButton()
{
    toggleButton(*(CButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO));
}
```

3) Add the toggle function to your subclass of CDialog

```
void toggleButton(CButton& theButton)
{
    switch(theButton.GetCheck())
    {
        case BST_UNCHECKED:
        {
            theButton.SetCheck(BST_CHECKED);
            break;
        }
        case BST_CHECKED:
        {
            theButton.SetCheck(BST_UNCHECKED);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            theButton.SetCheck(BST_UNCHECKED);
        }
    }
}
```